# May I use authorize.net rest api in flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, authorize.net

I’m working on small flutter mobile app for the us market.

My client chose authorize.net. Authorize.net does not have an official flutter plugin.

May I use rest api?  It looks much easier for me, rather than creating own plugin.

I would like to use:

- Apple Pay
- Google pay
- Credit cards
- E-check Payments.

Would it have any problems with google play or apple during publishing?

Comment: `Would it have any problems with google play or apple during publishing?` seems like a policy issue which people can't answer

Comment: Maybe someone already did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as much it is a restful API that you're integrating.